# changing cpu frequency dynamically depending on workload for power management

Tags: electrical-power, cpu-usage

I have the cpu-usage profile of some standard benchmarks in which I can see the cpu-usage to be varying a lot . I wish to increase the cpu-frequency to the highest available value , exactly at the instants the cpu starts executing compute-intensive portions of the workload and reduce the cpu-frequency at instants when workload is not compute-intensive.
I'm using linux OS, on a cluster of 2 core2duo machines

Please let me know what code I'm supposed to modify ? Should I change the P-state governor in order to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Just enable the "ondemand" cpufreq governor on your Linux distro. No need to modify any code.

On Redhat/Fedora, just install the cpuspeed package and and `chkconfig cpuspeed on` if it hasn't been done already by default.

Comment: Personally, I prefer 'conservative' because 'ondemand' cpu speeds tend to swing widely up and down while 'conservative' moves less.

Answer (score 0):

Most decent modern servers will manage this themselves - you haven't told us anything about your machine, processors, OS etc.

Comment: I'm using a cluster of 2 nodes running linux on core2duo processors

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

http://www.codon.org.uk/~mjg59/power/good_practices.html

TL;DR: you're better off running powertop and making sure your box can properly go idle(C states)